# Changing created through REST

Tags: rest, json

I was having a hard time getting my list items to POST back to the SharePoint list when I discovered if I delete the Modified and Created properties from the JSON it would work. The JSON that is being retrieved from the server looks like the following:

> "Created": "/Date(1455633698000)/",

Modified looks basically the same with a different number. Is there a way I can convert this so I can submit it with my POST? If I leave either one in the JSON I get a 400 error when I try to POST and if I delete both properties then everything works as intended. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/).

```
var created = moment("/Date(1455633698000)/");

var postBackData = {

   Title: "I'm a title",
   Created: created.toJSON()

};
```

You can also use MomentJS to format you dates very flexibly in the UI.

```
created.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); //February 16th 2016, 9:41:38 am
created.format('MM/DD/YYYY'); //02/16/2016
created.fromNow(); //10 hours ago
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) `DateTime` object returned by SP Rest queries are:

> represented in JSON as "/Date(number of ticks)/". The number of
>   ticks is a positive or negative long value that indicates the number
>   of ticks (milliseconds) that have elapsed since midnight 01 January,
>   1970 UTC. The maximum supported date value is MaxValue (12/31/9999
>   11:59:59 PM) and the minimum supported date value is MinValue
>   (1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM).

You can use below JS function to convert `JSON DateTime` object into native JS `DateTime`:

```
function parseDateFromJSON(jsonDateValue)
{
    return new Date(parseInt(json.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "$1")));
}
```

Usage:

```
var createdDate = parseDateFromJSON('/Date(1455633698000)/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since dates are always integers you can extract the datevalue as string with

```
"/Date(1455633698000)/".match(/\d+/)[0]
```

if you need the integer value cast it to a Number with +

```
+"/Date(1455633698000)/".match(/\d+/)[0]
```

SharePoint adds a `.format` prototype to the String object, so some of MomentJS good stuff (formatting dates) can be done without loading an extra library:

```
var myDate=new Date( +"/Date(1455633698000)/".match(/\d+/)[0] );
String.format( "{0:MM/dd/yy}" , myDate );
```

[MSDN String.format() Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
String.format("{0:i}",new Date());  outputs: Wed Oct 07 2015 20:39:54 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
String.format("{0:F}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39:54
String.format("{0:f}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39
String.format("{0:D}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015
String.format("{0:s}",new Date());  outputs: 2015-10-07T20:39:54
String.format("{0:d}",new Date());  outputs: 10/07/2015
String.format("{0:dd}",new Date());  outputs: 07
String.format("{0:ddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wed
String.format("{0:dddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday
String.format("{0:m}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:M}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:MM}",new Date());  outputs: 10
String.format("{0:MMM}",new Date());  outputs: Oct
String.format("{0:MMMM}",new Date());  outputs: October
String.format("{0:Y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:yy}",new Date());  outputs: 15
String.format("{0:yyyy}",new Date());  outputs: 2015
String.format("{0:gg}",new Date());  outputs: A.D.
String.format("{0:T}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39:54
String.format("{0:t}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39
String.format("{0:HH}",new Date());  outputs: 20
String.format("{0:mm}",new Date());  outputs: 39
String.format("{0:ss}",new Date());  outputs: 54
```

iDATE iDOC